# Must declare the scalar variable "@pList"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Requiero pasar una lista de Id's al `WHERE` de un `UPDATE`, iterando y haciendo un `UPDATE` a la vez, estos los obtengo a partir de hacer un `INSERT` a una tabla tipo `TYPE` con un value como tipo `INT`.

Algo así:

```
DECLARE @pList dbo.List
    ,@pUserAccount VARCHAR(50) = 'user@hotmail'
    ,@vCount INT;

INSERT INTO @pList (Value)
VALUES (174);

INSERT INTO @pList (Value)
VALUES (17);

SELECT @vCount = COUNT(*)
FROM @pList;

IF @vCount > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE Tbl
    SET StatusId = 2
    WHERE Id = @pList
END
```

Este es el error que me pasa:

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@pList".

Comment: Que intentas hacer con `DECLARE @pList  dbo.List`? por otro lado pareciera ser que por un lado `@pList`es una tabla y por otro la intentas usar como parámetro

Comment: Esto es un procedimiento almacenado? Si no, no veo caso que declares una variable que nunca varía, valga la redundancia, y además en el `WHERE` lo quieres usar como columna mientras que en el `INSERT` lo quieres usar como tabla, es algo inconsistente lo que pretendes hacer con ella.

Comment: Si bueno ese @pList es una tabla tipo Type a la cual luego utilizo como parametro y previamente tambien le hago un par de insert, despues que termina todo el sp los datos insertados se eliminan solos.

Comment: Si @Lixus es un procedimiento almacenado, el tema es que quiero actualizar registros de manera masiva en base a una lista de Id's que me proporcione el usuario, el "@pList" me guarda parcialmente esa lista por eso luego la utilizo como un parametro.

ya lo solucione ahorita les comparto mi solucion.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes algunos problemas, veamos:

#### 1. Declaración de una variable tipo Tabla

La forma correcta de hacerlo en SQL Server es:

```
DECLARE @pList TABLE(
    Value INT
)
```

#### 2. La sentencia de actualización

No puedes usar el `=` sino que debes usar el `IN` de la siguiente forma:

```
UPDATE Tbl
    SET StatusId = 2
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT Value FROM @pList)
```